# Why are text editors slow when editing very long lines?

Tags: algorithm, text-editor

Most text editors are slow when lines are very long. The suggested structure for data storage for text editor seems to be rope, which should be immune to long lines modification. By the way editors are even slow when simply navigating within long lines.

Example :
A single character like 0 repeated 100000 times in PSPad or 1000000 times in Vim on a single line slow the cursor moves when you are at the end of the line. If there is as much bytes in the file but dispatched on multiple lines the cursor is not slowed down at all so I suppose it's not a memory issue.

What's the origin of that issue that is so common ?

I'm mostly using Windows, so may be this is something related to Windows font handling ?

Comment: I never noticed this. What is a "very long" line?

Comment: I don't understand the close requests, I can't find the answer to my question in other questions. There are suggested algorithms but none that explain why it's slow despite rope implementation.

Comment: (+1) I know exactly what you're talking about, and I too don't understand the close requests. I think this is a perfectly reasonable question about data structures used to implement text editors. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Actually I tried with vim and you need much longer lines to notice an issue, like 1M characters on my PC. The cursor is faster at the beginning of the line and slower at the end. I'm sorry if the question is stupid, but I can't figure out what cause the slow down.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better in Programmers?

Comment: The question might be a Programmers thing but I'd like a algorithmic or low level programming explanation, so I think that it fits better on stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you edit to show the code in the editor that you're writing which is causing this actual problem that you face?

Comment: @BoltClock, that's exactly my question. I know that this is slightly silly but I don't understand what's the underlying problem here. Even if it's not optimized for this case, what is the issue that happen with long lines that makes it slow ? The case actually happens sometimes when you want to edit large json or xml files without expanding them still.

Comment: I accidentally my comment. Reposting: "'A single character like 0 repeated 100000 times' simply because nobody thought of optimizing their text editing components for lines **that long**? Most editors deal with lines in special ways related to vertical scrolling to improve performance there, they probably just didn't consider having to implement something similar for horizontal scrolling."

Comment: Look at rope data structure.  http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.9450&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @BoltClock: That's exactly the question. It is all too apparent that editors have not been designed to deal with lines of length 100000 or 1000000: we can see this for ourselves. The question is, what is it about the way text editors are implemented that makes them slow for such long lines? It's a question about the specific algorithms and data structures that go into typical implementations. Your comment does not answer it; at best it explains why editors have not been designed for such lines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably using a variable-length encoding like utf8.  The editor wants to keep track of what column you're in with every cursor movement, and with a variable-length encoding there is no shortcut to scanning every byte to see how many characters there are; with a long line that's a lot of scanning.

I suspect that you will not see such a slowdown with long lines using a single-byte encoding like iso8859-1 (latin1).  If you use a single-byte encoding then character length = byte length and the column can be calculated quickly with simple pointer arithmetic.  A fixed-length multibyte encoding like ucs-2 should be able to use the same shortcut (just dividing by the constant character size) but the editors might not be smart enough to take advantage of that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Was working with super long lines today in kate using UTF8 and it became impossible to work with. Changed encoding to ISO8859-1 and saw very significant performance bump. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As *evil otto* suggested, line encoding can force the line to be re-parse and for long lines this causes all sorts of performance issues.

But it is not only encoding that causes the line to be re-parsed.

Tab characters also require a full line scan, since you need to parse the whole line in order to calculate the true cursor location.

Certain syntax highlighting definitions (i.e. block comments, quoted strings etc) also require a full line parse.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned vim, so I'll assume that's the editor you use. Vim does not use a rope, as described [here](https://ecc-comp.blogspot.com/2015/05/a-brief-glance-at-how-5-text-editors.html) and [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Architectural-musing-and-ideas). It uses an array of lines, so your assumption that ropes should be immune to such long lines does not matter because ropes are not used.